# Returning xml into a textarea php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xml

thanks for clicking on my question, i'm having a problem with receiving response xml. my ajax function works by sending over the data to a php file, then the php file adds that data to an xml file while at the same time i want what the user entered to appear in a textarea in xml format. so far i know the php script sends the xml data to the xml which is great but i keep getting 500 errors when i try to return the data

here is the function

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = $(this).closest('form').serialize()+ '&submit=submit' ; 
    console.log(formData);
        var url = $("input[name='operation']:checked").val();
        var value = $("#submit").val();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(response){

            $('#xml_text').text(response);
            }
          });
      });

   });
 </script>
```

here is the php

```
<?php

//require_once('generate_error.php');
@date_default_timezone_set("GMT"); 
$xml= new DomDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
 $xml->formatOutput=true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace=false;
$xml->load('rates.xml');
//$today = date("F j, g:i a");

if(!$xml)
{
 $currencies=$xml->createElement("currencies");
 $xml->appendChild($currencies);
}
else
{
 $currencies=$xml->firstChild;
}

if (isset($_GET['submit']))
{
$curcode = $_GET['currencycode'];
$newrate = $_GET['rate'];
$cname = $_GET['currencyname'];
$countries = $_GET['countries'];


$curr=$xml->createElement("currency");
$currencies->appendChild($curr);


$currate=$xml->createElement("code",$curcode);
$curr->appendChild($currate);
$currate->setAttribute("rate",$newrate);


$name=$xml->createElement("cname",$cname);
$curr->appendChild($name);

$places=$xml->createElement("cntry",$countries);
$curr->appendChild($places);

$xml->save('rates.xml');


$xml =  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
$xml .= '<method type="put">';
$xml .= '<at>'.{$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']}.'</at>';
$xml .= '<rate>'.$newrate.'</rate>';
$xml .= '<curr>';
$xml .= '<code>'.$curcode.'</code>';
$xml .= '<name>'.$cname.'</name>';
$xml .= '<loc>';
$xml .= .$countries.;
$xml .= '</loc>';
$xml .= '</curr>';
$xml .= '</method>';
header('Content-type: text/xml');
return $xml;


}
?>
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Need to look at your error_log. If you don't know where it is, do `ini_get('error_log');` to find out. The cause of the 500 (internal server error) will be listed there. If you're still stuck, post the error here and we'll help further.

Comment: hey there thanks for replying, i have been trying to get the error logging working(never done it before) but it just won't work for me could this be because i am uploading this through a uni server?

Comment: What's the output of `echo ini_get('error_log');`...? Do you have a control panel, or ssh-ing in...?